# Fastest way to draw dynamic Angular (Conical) Gradient on iOS?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-animation, gradient

Using Core Graphics, traditionally the approach is drawing to a context, then drawing to screen. But for a dynamic (user changing values of colour and position) gradient this is woefully slow at any reasonable size, even on an iPad Air 2.

Is there some way to think about the maths of making a conical (nee Angular) gradient with Core Animation and avoiding the context performance issue, so as to permit rapid dynamic adjustment of the gradient?

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a library for drawing dynamic conical gradient in Swift: [AEConicalGradient](https://github.com/tadija/AEConicalGradient)

The approach I used in order to get better performance was drawing lines of different angles and colors to the center of the circle instead of drawing content pixel by pixel (less iterations).

Also what helped was turning on `drawsAsynchronously` property of the `CALayer`.

In the provided example you can see dynamic updating of gradient colors when changing device orientation, though it's still a little sluggish on bigger devices.

If someone has any idea how to improve performance even further, let's discuss here.

Comment: Well done! Do you know much about the cause of the banding at pure colours?

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid I don't understand what do you think with 'banding at pure colors'?